# Chrome inspector for CSS transitions/animations?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, web-inspector

I'm having a problem with my website design right before the CSS transition is starting, and I'd like to stop that transition to see what's going on in the DOM, is this possible with chrome inspector?

Comment: yes it is, what version of chrome and what type of css, then I will provide a screen shot with answer. also can you post a link to the current site ?

Comment: chrome 36.0.1985.143, css linear transition for margin property, the website is local so there's no link to send unfortunately.

Comment: If you provide me with a js fiddle il fix your problem after work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try to freeze the hover or animation, see screen shot or ask if you do not understand.
[image]

Click on the toggle element